# Repeating list in jquery-ui not displaying selected item in a select dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I'm using JS/JQuery to grab an li element from a ul and repeat it by inserting it into the DOM, at the same time I fill in some options in a select element. The select elements work OK but the selected item doesn't display on screen.

Plunker here https://plnkr.co/edit/izy7cXfFJxypLx30C8z3?p=preview

```
var rooms = [
{id: '001', roomName: 'Front Room'},
{id: '002', roomName: 'Kitchen'}
];
var salesItems = [
{id: '001', itemNo: '1', room_id: ''},
{id: '002', itemNo: '2', room_id: ''},
];

var itemTemplate = $('#basket-screen-ul').html();

$('#basket-screen-ul').html('');
var htmlList = '';

salesItems.forEach(function(salesItem) {
  console.log('item ' + salesItem.itemNo);
  var htmlItem = itemTemplate;
    for (var fld in salesItem) {
        htmlItem = app.replaceAll(htmlItem, '{saleItems.' + fld + '}', salesItem[fld]);
        htmlItem = app.replaceAll(htmlItem, 'saleItems-0-', 'saleItems-' + salesItem.itemNo +  '-');
    }
    htmlList += htmlItem;      
});
$('#basket-screen-ul').html(htmlList);
window.setTimeout(function() {
    salesItems.forEach(function(saleItem) {
        rooms.forEach(function(room) {
            $('#saleItems-' + saleItem.itemNo + '-rooms_id').append($('<option></option>').attr('value',room.id).text(room.roomName));
        });

    });
});
```

Is there something I need to do to make jquery-ui refresh over the newly inserted HTML?

Comment: Where is `button`? Also you use `setTimeout` with no time? It's really hard to figure out what you're trying to do.

Comment: `select` is a jQM widget that when enhanced, it adds `change` event listener to `select` element. You're copying DOM elements but not jQuery object. Anyway, replace `$(function () {` with `$(document).on("pagebeforecreate", function(){` in order to apply your changes before widget is created/enhanced.

Comment: Sorry Twisty, button is a red-herring, it was left over from the plunker's example code. Ultimately what I'm trying to achieve is something akin to Angular's ng-repeat where I can repeat as many <li> elements as I get from a database, this isn't necessarily just done at the page load but could be any time after that.

Comment: @Omar, that works great except in this case I will be loading the data long after the page has loaded.

Comment: I've modified the plunker to try to load the data on a button, this should show the problem in better light, see the effect on the right hand dropdown, it will still show "Two" even after picking a different option. [link]https://plnkr.co/edit/izy7cXfFJxypLx30C8z3?p=preview

Comment: in this case create a hidden template of `select` with `data-role="none"`, copy it, do changes and append it. When you append it, you need to call `.selectmenu()` in order to enhance it. or call `.enhanceWithin()` on containing div/wrapper. Dont forget to remove `data-role="none"` to enhance it.

Comment: Brilliant, that works, thanks @Omar